# Reorder database result

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, date

I need the results to show the most recent first - at the moment this code shows the updates in chronological order. Unfortunately I don't have access to the query in the below code so I need to run this within the code shown. Any ideas?

```
<?php
    if($updates)
    {
        foreach($updates as $up)
        {
?>
<li class="common_li" style="background:none; border:none; padding:0px;"> 

<p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:nornal; font-style:italic;  color:#999999;"> 

<?php echo date($site_setting['date_format'],strtotime($up['date_added'])); ?></p>

<div style="border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;" class="detail_update">

<?php echo $up['updates'] ; ?></div>
</li>
?>
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be, to modify the query that lead to `$updates`. If this is a mysql_query, for example, it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Is there some mysql query, you have access to?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the query so I need to run this within the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out where the `$updates` variable is coming from and change the query there.

Another option is to sort the variable by the `date_added` key:

```
function sort_by_date( $a, $b ) {
   return strtotime( $a[ 'date_added' ] ) - strtotime( $b[ 'date_added' ] );
}

usort( $updates, "sort_by_date" );
```

Changing the query is the cleaner way, so I recommend doing that if at all possible.

Comment: Hmmmm, no change. No errors though. Currently they are in date order (oldest result first), I need them to show the newest result first. Any ideas how to reverse the order result?

Comment: You can reverse the variables in the function. `return strtotime( $b[ 'date_added' ] ) - strtotime( $a[ 'date_added' ] );`